# How to store tenant external API credentials securely using .NET7 / EF + SQL Server / Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, security

My app has several tenants, which in turn have several users. Each of the tenants use several external API's that collect data and store it in my service. I will need to use the tenants API credentials (UserName, Password) to access these external services. How would one do this securely?

Would some kind of two way encryption be the best way to go about this? The way I've done it for now is to save all the credentials in Azure Keyvault and getting them in my code using a function which looks somethings like this:

```
public record ApiCredentials(string UserName, string Password);

...

public static ApiCredentials GetApiCredentials(this IConfiguration configuration, 
                                               string tenantId,
                                               string credentialNamespace)
{
    return new ApiCredentials(
        configuration[$"{tenantId}-{credentialNameSpace}:Username"],
        configuration[$"{tenantId}-{credentialNameSpace}:Password"]);
}
```

While the above works and is pretty secure, it feels kind of hacky and I'm not sure I'm going about this in the right way.

Are there any standard practices around this?

Comment: _"I will need to use the tenants API credentials (UserName, Password) to access these external services."_ - Can you still change this Design decision? Why don't you provide an api to _push_ their data to?

Comment: @Fildor I can't really. So for more context: I will have to integrate to four different services that provide the same data in different formats which the clients will bring with them. I can't sign up to these services and charge the cost to them because of legislation. Therefore I will need to create an API-layer that ties all of them together under a unified API, but the service I call will change based on which of the services the client have an agreement with.

Comment: Aye, that's going to be a pia. But anyway,  if we are talking Azure, I don't see credentials anywhere other than KeyVault.

Comment: Yeah. Well I guess my integration to Azure Keyvault will be as good as it gets. @Fildor